# Tensorflow Rank undefined Error while training variable length sequences with batch size = 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am doing a classification task.
As one example, I have a string and a label(1/0). The string is composed of fixed set of characters So I have tokenized the characters and one-hot encoded it and due to variable length sequences batched to size 1. My input for each time step is a one hot encoded vector of size maxid = 7 since my timesteps are variable I have put None and used a batch size of 1.

Before Batching One example looks like this

```
tf.Tensor([3 1 3 1 0 6 6 5 1 5], shape=(10,), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor(0, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Shape of Items

```
for X, Y in dataset.take(3):
    print(X.shape, Y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(10,) ()
(15,) ()
(9,) ()
```

> TimeSteps - Variable,  Batch Size - 1, Feature Vector Length for Each Timestep - 7

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()
dataset = dataset.batch(1)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda X_batch, Y_batch : (tf.one_hot(X_batch, depth = max_id), Y_batch))
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
for X_batch, Y_batch in dataset.take(3):
    print(X_batch.shape, Y_batch.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1, 9, 7) (1,)
(1, 10, 7) (1,)
(1, 9, 7) (1,)
```

Model:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape = [None,max_id]),
        keras.layers.LSTM(128),
        keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = 'accuracy')

model.fit(dataset, epochs = 10, steps_per_epoch=total_size/2)
```

Error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.
```

Comment: I think the shape of labels should be (1, 1) not (1,)

Comment: Tried that Still Didn't work, Now My X_batch, Y_batch shape is `(1, variable, 7) (1, 1)` Shall I add the collab link?

Comment: No. Your model works with fixed dimensions like (1, 10, 7), (1, 1). So I think the problem relates to usage of flexible dimension. I dont know how could it be solved. I would just use separate datasets for every sequence length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems [RaggedTensor](https://androidkt.com/training-rnn-model-with-variable-length-sequences-in-keras-using-raggedtensor/) fixes this issue without needing batch_size of 1 or padding the sequences, it seamingly also integrates with Data API with no issues.

[Docs Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#keras)